# Compute contour of a binary image using matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, contour

I am trying to compute contour of a binary image. Currently i identify the first non zero and the last non zero pixel in the image through looping. Is there a better way? i have encountered few functions:

```
imcontour(I)
bwtraceboundary(bw,P,fstep,conn,n,dir)
```

But the first doesn't return the x and y coordinates of the contour. The second function requires a seed point which i cannot provide. An example of the image is shown below. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: But if you already have a binary image, why can't you follow the steps outlined in this [Matlab tutorial](http://www.mathworks.com/examples/image/2101-trace-boundaries-of-objects-in-images) ?

Comment: It requires a seed point "Determine the row and column coordinates of a pixel on the border of the object you want to trace bwboundary uses this point as the starting location for the boundary tracing.". I cant do that.

Comment: Why can you not do that?

Comment: @rayryeng looks like he is mad at you now and gave me the answer hahaha btw, congrats for the gold badge!

Comment: @imaluengo lol thanks :)

Comment: @rayryeng I've realized the questions where your answers aren't accepted are voted down. So I tried changing other accepted answers as well turns out only for Questions that you have answered I get voted down. So i assume u like to vote down people who don't accept your answer. I might be wrong in that case i am sorry.

Comment: Yes you're wrong. Sorry to say. It's certainly your prerogative to accept whatever you want. It just seems that your behaviour is malicious. Either way I will keep this in mind if I decide to answer any of your questions in the future. I didn't down vote but it may be perhaps other people who didn't agree with your changed accepted answer. I can't control what they do.

Comment: @rayryeng Well It did look like you. And from my point of view your behavior was malicious. Regardless you were kind enough to answer. And I once again I would like to apologize. 
If i go to your profile and down vote all your work will u know its me? I don't think so but i bet you will assume so.

Comment: @user2307268 Yes, I would agree that it is a valid assumption.  However, just to make it very clear, I only downvote questions / answers that are incorrect, not well formed, or don't answer the question (if it's an answer).  Your questions (from what I have seen) are not this way and so I've never downvoted.  In fact, I've only upvoted your questions / answers.  In any case, let's move past this.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@rayryeng have already provided the correct answer. As another approach (might be that `bwperim` performs this operations internally) boundaries of a `binary` image can be obtained by calculating the difference between the dilated and the eroded image.

For a given image:

```
im = im2bw(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAZ5L.png'));
```

and a given binary structural element:

```
selem = ones(3,3); %// square, 8-Negihbours
% selem = [0 1 0; 1 0 1; 0 1 0]; %// cross, 4-Neighbours
```

The contour of the object can be extracted as:

```
out = imerode(im, selem) ~= imdilate(im, selem);
```

[image]

Here, however, the boundary is *thicker* than using `bwperim`, as the pixels are masked in both inside and outside of the object.

Comment: Dilation subtracted by erosion is certainly a valid approach. +1.

Comment: I think you really only need one or the other (i.e. just an erosion *or* a dilation). For example: `out = im & ~imerode(im, selem);` This will give a thinner line.

Comment: @gnovice yes, but the contour would be either inside or outside the object. For different applications one might be better than the other, that is rather subjective.

Answer (score 6):

I'm surprised you didn't see `bwperim`.  Did you not try [`bwperim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwperim.html)?  This finds the perimeter pixels of all closed objects that are white in a binary image.  Using your image directly from StackOverflow:

```
im = im2bw(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAZ5L.png')); 
out = bwperim(im);
imshow(out);
```

We get:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, stumbled across this question and just wanted to add that  `imcontour(Img);`   does return a matrix. The first row contains the x-values, the second row contains the y-values.

`contour = imcontour(Img); x = contour(1,:); y = contour(2,:);`

But I would discard the first column.

Comment: [Here is the definition of the array returned](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.contour-properties.html#budgut_-ContourMatrix). The first column gives the number of elements in the contour. If there are multiple contours, they will be concatenated, you need to use this number of elements to know where to cut the array.

Comment: Oh, cool, thank you. I wondered what these numbers were meant for.